# Nuxt i18n : how to avoid duplicated translation keys

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm using Nuxt, Nuxt i18n and in component translations :

```js
<template>
  <div>{{ $t("Hello world") }}</div>
</template>

<i18n lang="yaml">
fr:
  Hello world: Bonjour le monde
</i18n>
```

My problem is that this code "doesn't work" in english and display "Bonjour le monde" because no translation is found in english while I would like it to stay "Hello world". To make it work, I have to redeclare it as so :

```js
<template>
  <div>{{ $t("Hello world") }}</div>
</template>

<i18n lang="yaml">
fr:
  Hello world: Bonjour le monde
en:
  Hello world: Hello world
</i18n>
```

So it seems like too much effort to translate my texte only 1 time.

I took a good look at the doc but maybe I am missing something :( Here is my i18n configuration :

```js
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/i18n',
  ...
],
i18n: {
  vueI18nLoader: true,
  langDir: 'locales/',
  lazy: true,
  loadLanguagesAsync: true,
  locales: [
    {
      code: "en",
      name: "English",
      iso: 'en-US',
      file: 'en.js'
    },
    {
      code: "fr",
      name: "Français",
      iso: 'fr-FR',
      file: 'fr.js'
    },
  ],
  defaultLocale: "en",
  strategy: 'prefix',
  parsePages: false
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the ambiguity here is about how to use translation keys. Currently, you're trying to use `"Hello world"` both as the key to map to a translation as well as the translation itself. While not technically wrong, it feels misleading. If you use keys similar to [the examples given in docs](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/per-component-translations), your code will be both less verbose as well as easier to grok since the two usages (key and value) are separate.

Comment: lets say that by doing so I avoid the pain of having to find keys in addition to doing the translation but it seems like it would not be a reccomended practice so I might have to go with the keys

Comment: I've suggested you an extension below my answer, to not have to find a key and so on, that one helps quite a lot with the whole i18n process. Ah yeah, this is how everybody does i18n from what I've seen so far (in JS, Ruby, PHP, etc...).

Comment: @jiboulex The problem with using translations directly as keys means that if you change the English translation you'll have to go and modify every other language definition to use the new key as well. Whereas if you use keys as show in the docs, changing the translation for one language doesn't affect others.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, we decided to go with the translation key approach !

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite cumbersome if you use it with the `<i18n>` tag as shown in your question.

Meanwhile, this is the [usual approach](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/options-reference#locales) regarding how to use i18n across a bigger project.

Pretty much as shown [here too](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#html), you will be using the following in your code

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
</div>
```

While having some `fr.json` and `en.json` locales in your project.

Then, it can be as simple as automating [a merge](https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge) between your 2 JSON files if needed.

---

Here is a basic configuration on how to work with JSON

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/i18n',
],
i18n: {
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  langDir: 'locales/',
  lazy: true,
  loadLanguagesAsync: true,
  locales: [
    {
      code: "en",
      iso: 'en',
      file: 'en.json'
    },
    {
      code: "fr",
      iso: 'fr',
      file: 'fr.json'
    },
  ],
  vueI18n: {
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
  }
},
```

`/locales/fr.json`

```json
{
  "helloWorld": "Salut le monde"
}
```

`/locales/en.json`

```json
{
  "helloWorld": "hello world"
}
```

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-link :to="switchLocalePath('en')">Change to English</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link :to="switchLocalePath('fr')">Passer en Francais</nuxt-link>
    <p>here is the i18n string {{ $t('helloWorld') }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

With the actual result

[image]

Clicking on each link will properly change the locale regarding the one in the JSON file.

---

Here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt2-example-i18n) if you want a working example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I get that but it doesn't fit my needs, I wish there was a config to tell "don't search for a translation in this language"

Comment: @jiboulex there is nothing better than [this one](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#te), but there is nothing similar to "don't search for a translation in this language". I mean, if you want to have a website with 3 locales (`fr`, `en` and `es`), get 3 files and translate them accordingly. If you have some `it` but no translation, what would be the use case to have such part in your code? The approach to i18n is to translate a given key. You could create your own helper function. This extension could help you quite a lot too: https://github.com/lokalise/i18n-ally Really nice for i18n.